# How to integrate the function $ \sqrt{1+x^2}· x^5 $?

Tags: integration

Can someone help me find the integral of $ \sqrt{1+x^2}·x^5 $ ?

I guess it's done by integration by parts, however, I can't figure out what to do with the square root, since I keep integrating that term over and over again if I do it by parts..

Comment: change variable to $u = \sqrt{x^2+1}$ and notice $xdx = udu \implies \sqrt{x^2+1}x^5dx = u(u^2-1)^2 udu$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Use the substitution 
$$
1+x^2=t \quad \rightarrow \quad 2x dx = dt
$$

and:
$$
x^2=t-1 \quad \rightarrow \quad x^5 dx=(x^2)^2 x dx=(t-1)^2\cdot \frac{1}{2}dt
$$

Answer (score 0):

Another way: notice that

$$\int x^5\sqrt{1+x^2}\ dx=\frac{1}{2}\int2x\cdot x^4\sqrt{1+x^2}\ dx$$

Now substitute $x^2=y$, so $2xdx=dy$

$$\frac{1}{2}\int2x\cdot x^4\sqrt{1+x^2}\ dx=\frac{1}{2}\int y^2\sqrt{1+y}\ dy$$

You can now substitute again $\sqrt{1+y}=z$, then $y=z^2-1$ and $dy=2z\ dz$

$$\frac{1}{2}\int y^2\sqrt{1+y}\ dy=\int\left(z^2-1\right)^2z^2\ dz=\int \left(z^6-2z^4+z^2\right)\ dz=\frac{z^7}{7}-\frac{2}{5}z^5+\frac{z^3}{3}+c$$

Finally we have

$$\int x^5\sqrt{1+x^2}\ dx=\frac{\sqrt{(1+x^2)^7}}{7}-\frac{2\sqrt{(1+x^2)^5}}{5}+\frac{\sqrt{(1+x^2)^3}}{3}+c$$

for all $c\in\mathbb{R}$.